# Sentence detection - In first sentence find two NP and then go to the next sentence

Tags: python, nltk

I have an annotated dataset, first I used the sent_tokenizer from nltk to detect the sentence. Now I have to define a feature like to check if both i and j (noun phrases) are in the first sentence and do some work then it should go to the next sentence and again define the i and j and do the same work. How to do it in python?

This is the first sentence I detected from the dataset:

```
در
همین
حال
،
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
 نجیب
 الله
 خواجه
 عمری
،
</coref>
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="np" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">

سرپرست
وزارت
تحصیلات
عالی
افغانستان
</coref>
گفت
که
در
سه
ماه
گذشته
در
۳۳
ولایت
کشور
.
```

Now - how to write the code that if it detects the first sentence. it checks for i and j if they are in one sentence return True. and then go to the next sentence.

```
 for sentence in sent_tokenize(text):
    print(sentence) # it will print all the sentences
    if i_NP ... and j_NP:
         return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you actually want to `yield` the result rather than `return` it. Return breaks out of the function whereas yield will return you an item at a time. Maybe something like this:

```
if all([x in sentence for x in [i_NP, j_NP]]):
    yield sentence
```

if statement checks all words are in sentence, and if they are yields the sentence from the function

Comment: How it knows the value of i_NP and j_NP. I tried your code, it does not print any error and result.

Comment: I was under the impression that you were defining i_NP and j_NP and this was part of a larger function. That is the context within which this will work. If you just want to print the result and not yield it, change the `yield` for a `print(sentence)`

Comment: ok, but how to know the value of i_NP and j_NP in a sentence. I can't give it manually, because in each sentence, the value will be changed.